# Is there a mod_python for Apache HTTP Server 2.2 and Python 2.6 or 3.0?

Tags: python, apache2, mod-python

I poked around the [mod_python website](http://www.modpython.org/) and I only found the files for Python 2.5 and earlier for Apache HTTP Server 2.2. I Googled around a little, without significant luck. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use mod_wsgi.

mod_python has been stagnant for a while now. Most of the effort for python web apps has been going into mod_wsgi.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it in more detail tomorrow, but it appears that it might be what I'm looking for.

Comment: +1: There doesn't appear to have been a source check-in on the mod_python project in about 8 months (unless I'm looking at the wrong repository), which pre-dates the official release of Python 2.6.0.

Comment: +1 and, to add to Jarret's comment, the only commits to mod_python in the last 14-15 months are almost all bug fixes and were done by the author of mod_wsgi, Graham Dumpleton.

Comment: +1 and, I might add, mod_python sucks when it comes to run python web applications. It is more suited to writing apache extension modules. mod_wsgi is the PEP-standartized way to go.